# Remove all non default permissions from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, database-permissions

I have messed up a SQL Server database that I need to delete all permission on. I need to keep the built in permissions.

What is the best way to handle this? Is there somebody with a script out there? Or is possible to restore a database without the permission?

Comment: What do you mean by *delete all permissions*? You have granted to users more than they need to?

Comment: Developer wants to start over. One way is to copy all tables, sp, views etc new empty database without users and permissions. Then extract data to new database. Or if someone has script that remove all permission and users... Some generic revoke script on all user create objects

Comment: Just drop all the users and re-add them. And remove any permissions added to the public role if any.